# Tab Navigator depreciated and createBottomTabNavigator isn't working with my code

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a project that uses the old depreciated "Tab Navigator" and I'm trying to incorporate can "createBottomTabNavigator" instead-but I'm encountering some issues can someone please help me?

My code below:

```
     import React, {Component} from "react";
     import {View, StyleSheet, CameraRoll} from "react-native";
     import {MainFeed, Login, Camera, Profile } from "./components/screens";
     import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
     import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";


  const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({

     feed: MainFeed,
   camera: Camera,
 profile: Profile

 });


  const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator({
    login:{screen:Login},
    main: {screen: MainFeed}
 });

  const AppContainer =createAppContainer(MainStack);


   class InstaClone2 extends React.Component {
       render() {
    return  <AppContainer/>;

  }
}

export default InstaClone2;
```

The error message photo is below I don't know how to program "createBottomTabNavigator" in my app I read the documentation on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html and I still don't understand how to incorporate it in my current code. Can someone please give me a written detailed example of how I can incorporate it into my current code? It would be greatly appreciated.

Photo of Error Message:

[image]

Comment: You are using `react-navigation` V5. If you want to use `createBottomTabNavigator` like that i would suggest to downgrade to V4. If you still want to use V5, you need to follow the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/en/)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to download V4 I'm in my package.json file but I don't know exactly what to click on or how to change it because it says                                     ("dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.7",                                                                     
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.13",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.1",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.1"
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.7",   )                  How would I change it to version version 4?

Comment: What exactly do I need to enter? And in which field?

Comment: Here's the guide with the correct way to get createBottomTabNavigator: [URL](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/bottom-tab-navigator.html)
You are using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` and it is specifically designed for `react-navigation` 5

Comment: Thank you so much! My code is finally functional again. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked!